# connection with sqlite database from fragments in the tabbed activity of android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-tabbed-activity

***I have successfully inserted data into sqlite database. But unable to display it in fragment, pls help....***

**This is my fragment code.**

```
public class abpos extends Fragment{

    DataBaseHelper myDb;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.abpos, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**This is my database connector file.**

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bbloodd.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "bbloodstablee";


     public static final String COL_1 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_2 = "GROOUP";
    public static final String COL_3 = "mob";


    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" (NAME TEXT,GROOUP TEXT,mob TEXT PRIMARY KEY)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME);


        onCreate(db);


    }

    public boolean insertData(String names,String groupss,String mobs) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1,names);
        contentValues.put(COL_2,groupss);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,mobs);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
        return result != -1;
    }




    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `getAllData()`?

Comment: To display the all contents...in that fragment....pls help

Comment: How can i display the contents in the fragment ? Pls help sir

Comment: getAllData() need to be called in fragment abpos